# Undefined reference to stdscr

Tags: c, linux, gcc, g++, undefined-reference

I want to compile a C code in the latest version of ubuntu. when I do this, I get the following error:

```
gcc <fileName>.c
```

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccY8CJ10.o: in function `main':
sudoku.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `stdscr'
/usr/bin/ld: sudoku.c:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `wgetch'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Do you have any idea what causes this?
I know the problem is `<curses.h>` header in my code, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You must link with the curses library: `gcc fileName.c -lcurses`

Comment: thanks, It worked. I used to place the flag before filename

Comment: Great, you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `-lcurses`. Ex: `gcc main.c -o demo -lcurses`